# I want to execute a function when the Flutter app starts

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send an ID to the server and receive json when the app is launched.

Flow
1.Start my app (Show splash screen)
2.Json request to server
3.If there is data, display page1. If not, display page2

Comment: What have you tried?? and what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I have n’t tried it yet.

Comment: I want to get data from the server when the app starts.
But I do n’t know how.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data might be of help.

Comment: Try this article : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-fetching-parsing-json-data-c019ddddaa34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you my need to get a bit more learning about Flutter, my sugest is to start with this one [only 10 euros](https://www.appbrewery.co/courses/enrolled/548873) will give you base from where will be easier to learn the rest, that said, to get a databse i'm using this code:

```
//lib/services/networking_service.dart

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class NetworkHelper {
  final String json;
  final url = 'HERE YOU CAN PUT YOUR API URL';

  NetworkHelper(this.json);

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  };

  Future getData(BuildContext context) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(url, body: json, headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(decodedResp);
      return decodedResp;
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

You can call it from your main like this:

```
      static getCategories(BuildContext context) async {
        String json =
            'q={"f":"listCategories","Store_id":"$storeId","LANG":"$lang","UID":"$uid"}';
//THIS json VARIABLE IS WHERE YOU NEED TO PUT YOUR API CALL LÓGIC TO GET THAT ID, I LEAVE THIS FOR YOUR BETTER UNDERSTANDING
        NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(json);
        var decodedResp = await networkHelper.getData(context);
        final CategoriesModel respData = CategoriesModel.fromJson(decodedResp);
        print(respData);
        //HERE YOU MAY RETURN O STORE IN PROVIDER YOUR RESPONSE AND SEND THE USER TO THE PAGE YOU CONSIDER
      }
```

If you need more help I'm happy to help, but consider taking the course o learn a bit more, it will be lots more easy and enjoyable after.

Answer (score 1):

use `SchedulerBinding` it runs when page is opened and widgets are build.

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // your code after page opens,splash keeps open until work is done
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
Timer(
    Duration(seconds: 3),// you can do your stuff here when splash screen run

        () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen())));}
```

and please put this code into the spalsh screen